# Multiple Annotations On Mapkit for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, google-maps, mapkit

Does anyone know how to display more than one location on a map Using Database?

I am trying to drop Multiple Pins on google Map with the help of database but just able to drop last pin

Comment: I think I know. but without seeing your code it is impossible to find your mistake in it...

Comment: Just to echo Vladimir's request - please post your code.

Answer (score 2):

```
Below is the function which i m using to fill array with the help of Database


RecipieAppDelegate *appDelegate = (RecipieAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate getallrecords];
    self.namesArray=appDelegate.rs;
    ///filling array with database
        for (int i=0; i<namesArray.count; i++) {
        Food *product = (Food *)[self.namesArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"%d",i);
        appDelegate.mylatitude=product.Latitude;
        appDelegate.mylongitude=product.Longitude;
     /// this function is use to call the class which is use to drop pin on map 
     BridgeAnnotation *BridgePin = [[BridgeAnnotation alloc] init];
     [self.mapAnnotations insertObject:BridgePin atIndex:kBridgeAnnotationIndex];
     [BridgePin release];

    }


/////CLASS BRIDGE ANNOTATION   below is the function getting cordinate from above function n droping pin    
    - (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;
    {
        RecipieAppDelegate *appDelegate = (RecipieAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        Food *product;
        CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
    //  theCoordinate.latitude = 37.810000;
    //  theCoordinate.longitude = -122.477989;
        theCoordinate.latitude = [appDelegate.mylatitude doubleValue];
        NSLog(@"%f",    theCoordinate.latitude);
        theCoordinate.longitude = [appDelegate.mylongitude doubleValue];
        NSLog(@"%f",    theCoordinate.longitude);
        return theCoordinate; 
    }
```

well I run loop perfectly on array 5 times but its pass the last value to second function

awaiting for you reply

Comment: You don't change the value of kBridgeAnnotionIndex. All your BridgePin are inserted in the same index !

Where are you calling the method coordinate ?

Comment: well i m defining bridgeannotionindex like this  enum
{
   kBridgeAnnotationIndex
};
   and calling - (IBAction)cityAction:(id)sender
{
     [self.mapView addAnnotation:[self.mapAnnotations objectAtIndex:kCityAnnotationIndex]];
}
 can you please correct my code

Comment: Try change to change kBridgeAnnotationIndex with i. But it's difficult whithout more code.

Comment: well i already but pins are overlapping on each other but it drops pin 20 time on same coordinate i m sick of this honestly :(